# How ti get the size of eBPF map?

Tags: ebpf

I'm new to eBPF, I want to insert elements to a BPF_ARRAY, so is there any way to do like C++ `push_back()`  `size()`  function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can change elements in an array map (through the system call `bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, ...)`), but you cannot dynamically resize your map at this time (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63268838/3716552)), although this might be possible in the future as [some work](https://lpc.events/event/7/contributions/681/) in that direction has been presented before.

So for now you have a fixed-size array that you can update either from your BPF program, or from user space. For the user space side, in C++, you probably want to use libbpf to update your map. You have a low-level wrapper around the syscall in bpf.h, [`bpf_map_update_elem()`](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/29869d6ef0893cc1c907705f919fdfd6feb7cc13/src/bpf.h#L194), as well as a higher-level function that works on map objects managed by the library, in libbpf.h: [`bpf_map__update_elem()`](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/29869d6ef0893cc1c907705f919fdfd6feb7cc13/src/libbpf.h#L1073).

To answer to the question from your title: Yes you can obtain the map size, again through the `bpf()` system call. Libbpf provides a wrapper: [`bpf_obj_get_info_by_fd()`](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/29869d6ef0893cc1c907705f919fdfd6feb7cc13/src/bpf.h#L444), which fills a [`struct bpf_map_info`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L5880) from which you can retrieve the size of the map.